# In vim how to search forward ignoring the newline?

Tags: vim

In vim `f >` takes me to the next occurrence of `>` on the same line, but it doesn't work if `>` occurs on another line. How do I get the forward search to ignore newlines?

I couldn't find the answer in the help text around near `:h f`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fFtT` are "left-right motions" and as such only work on the current line. This is by design and no option whatsoever exists to change that behavior.

Either you use `?/` (awesome with `set incsearch`) which are the actual shortcuts for "search backward" and "search forward" or a plugin like [ft_improved](https://github.com/chrisbra/improvedft), [Fanf,ingTastic;](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic), [PreciseJump](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3437) or [EasyMotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion)

Answer (score 1):

[easymotion.vim](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) plugin is what you need.